# Table Self join

Tags: sql, oracle, join, inner-join

Table_a has columns : old_id and new_id . Following query gives  planning region and organization code for old_id.

```
 SELECT   a.old_id,d.planning_region,b.organization_code 
            FROM  table_a  a 
                     INNER JOIN table_b b ON a.old_id = b.organization_id
                     INNER JOIN table_c c ON c.organization_code = b.organization_code
                     INNER JOIN table_d d ON d.planning_location_id = b.organization_code
```

My requirement is  get  organization code for new_id too. So my output will be like this

old_id, planning_region ( of old_id ), organization_code (of old_id ) and organization_code (of new_id ).

Self Join should work but here in this case, Do I need to do self join of all 4 tables ?

Note:  new_id also can be joined same as old_id with table_b.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, you can add more joins.

If you just want the new `organization_code`:

```
SELECT 
    a.old_id,
    d.planning_region,
    b.organization_code,
    b1.organization_code organization_code_new
FROM  table_a  a 
INNER JOIN table_b b  ON a.old_id = b.organization_id
INNER JOIN table_c c  ON c.organization_code = b.organization_code
INNER JOIN table_d d  ON d.planning_location_id = b.organization_code  
INNER JOIN table_b b1 ON a.new_id = b1.organization_id
```

If you also want the `planning_region`, then we need to bring `d` as well:

```
SELECT 
    a.old_id,
    d.planning_region,
    b.organization_code, 
    d1.planning_region planning_region_new,
    b1.organization_code organization_code_new
FROM  table_a  a 
INNER JOIN table_b b  ON a.old_id = b.organization_id
INNER JOIN table_c c  ON c.organization_code = b.organization_code
INNER JOIN table_d d  ON d.planning_location_id = b.organization_code  
INNER JOIN table_b b1 ON a.new_id = b1.organization_id
INNER JOIN table_c c1 ON a.new_id = c1.organization_id
INNER JOIN table_d d1 ON d1.planning_location_id = b1.organization_code
```

Side note: it is not obvious what the purpose of table `c` is in the query (apart, maybe, filtering?).

Comment: C is just have that org code present in a particular table.

Comment: @arc: OK so that's filtering. It makes sense.

Comment: Thank you @GMB!  You may need to update INNER JOIN table_b c1 ON a.new_id = c1.organization_id  ( last but one line ) as  INNER JOIN table_c c1 ON a.new_id = c1.organization_id Addition to that I created index on the  new_id column and it worked! Thanks :)